# The trait `IntoWasmAbi` is not implemented for `HashMap<i32, i32>

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-cargo, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm

Trying to compile following `rust` code to `wasm` to make it compatible running with existing js. Trying to return hashmaped value from function.

**lib.rs**

```
    use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
    use std::collections::HashMap;

   #[wasm_bindgen]
    pub fn get_transformed_filters()-> HashMap<i32, i32> { 
        let mut hm = HashMap::new();
        for i in 1..9990000 {
            hm.insert(i + i, i * i);
        }  
        return hm 
    }
```

Console error after running command `wasm-pack build`

```
[INFO]:   Checking for the Wasm target...
[INFO]:   Compiling to Wasm...
   Compiling hello-wasm v0.1.0 (/Users/mfe/ui/rustService/test-wasm)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `HashMap<i32, i32>: IntoWasmAbi` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:15:1
   |
15 | #[wasm_bindgen]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `IntoWasmAbi` is not implemented for `HashMap<i32, i32>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `ReturnWasmAbi` for `HashMap<i32, i32>`
   = note: this error originates in an attribute macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `test-wasm`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
Error: Compiling your crate to WebAssembly failed
Caused by: failed to execute `cargo build`: exited with exit code: 101
  full command: "cargo" "build" "--lib" "--release" "--target" "wasm32-unknown-unknown"
```

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: You can't return complex data types from functions exposed to WASM https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/arbitrary-data-with-serde.html

Comment: Thanx.  I should read all its docs